# Struts 2 map default action on specific namespace

Tags: struts2, mapping

I want to have an action mapping on each "/mobile/*" urls.

When I put the folowing in my struts.xml :

```
<package name="default-mobile-action" extends="mobile-default">  
   <action name="*.*" class="ca.tink.vitrine.webapp.action.DefaultAction">         
   ....      
   </action>  
</package>
```

My "/mobile/*" urls go to the default action, that is correct. 
But when I change the mapping like that (I add a namespace on "/mobile") :

```
<package name="default-mobile-action" extends="mobile-default" namespace="/mobile">  
   <action name="*.*" class="ca.tink.vitrine.webapp.action.DefaultAction">         
   ....      
   </action>  
</package>
```

Now, the "/mobile/*" urls dont access the action (no action is found...)

It is realy not the behaviour I expected...

What did I missed?

Comment: See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/namespace-configuration.html, http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/action-configuration.html and http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html.

Comment: for interested people : https://www.coderanch.com/t/610039/Struts/Mapping-default-actions

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <include file="mobile.xml"></include>
</struts>
```

mobile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

    <package name="mobile" extends="struts-default" namespace="/mobile">
    </package>
</struts>
```